# WordPress After migration some images src is empty

Tags: images, migration

I have moved my WordPress website from Hostwind server to Contabo Server. But after migration Some images showing like this

```
<img src=""/>
```

And some image are looking fine. I can't understand what is issue? I try to search But nothing found. any help please.

***I used Commandline method for moving files (using SCP Command) and DB migration is simple import export.***

Comment: Were you using a CDN with the old host? Where are you seeing the images showing with an empty source - in the front end developer tools, or in the database itself?

Comment: In frontend Developer tool. No CDN using ni old server not even in new server

Comment: What kind of method did you use to migrate? Please, [supplement](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/349591/edit) your question with the missing useful information.

Comment: I used Commanline method for moving files (using SCP Command) and DB migration is simple import export.

Comment: Does these _some images_ belongs to the content or to a theme or a plugin? Do you see empty `<img src="" />`  in the XML file you've exported or in the dump of the old database? Have you compared checksums of old and new installation? This is useful information that you already had to provide in the question.

Comment: Images That are showing is Post Featured images. Image that are showing as "<img src="">" available in Database.

Comment: Check here
http://www.ifashionnetwork.com/